# How do I make a simple program to output a pyramid of two symbols:one printed twice as the other using loops in C++?

Tags: c++, loops

I want:

```
*!!
**!!!!
***!!!!!!
// And so on.
```

My attempt is below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    int ex;
    for (a = 1; a <= 5; a++)
    {
        cout<<"*";
        for(ex =1; ex<= 2*a; ex++)
        {
            cout<<"!";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get this as the output:

```
*!!
*!!!!
*!!!!!!
//and so on...
```

It does what I need it to do for the second symbol but I don't know how to arrange the loops so that first symbol is outputted the desired number of times and not cut off by the second loop.

Comment: Um, within the line, you don't have the `cout << '*'` in a loop ...

Comment: As an aside, it's more idiomatic to use `for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)` - half-open ranges are usually closed on the left, e.g. array indexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is a small logical mistake in your code, you are only printing **'*'** once every loop. use the code below

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    int ex;
    for (a = 1; a <= 5; a++)
    {
        cout<<std::string((a),'*');
        cout<<std::string((a*2),'!');
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the `cout << '*'` statement in a loop as well:

```
int main()
{
    int a;
    int ex;
    for (a = 1; a <= 5; a++) // signifies the number of lines to print
    {
        auto i = 1;
        while (i <= a) // prints * a times
        {
            cout<<"*";
            ++i;
        }
        for(ex =1; ex<= 2*a; ex++) // prints ! 2*a times
        {
            cout<<"!";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need another loop to print a-counted * symbols inside the main loop.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    int ex;
    for (a = 1; a <= 5; a++)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < a; ++i)
        {
            cout<<"*";
        }
        for(ex =1; ex<= 2*a; ex++)
        {
            cout<<"!";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The loop iteration is high, it is not an optimal code, though you should check the next answer of @pavan, probably a better approach!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int times = 5;

    char simbol1 = '*', simbol2 = '!';

    for(int i=1 ; i<=times ; i++){
        for(int k=0; k<i; k++) cout << simbol1;
        for(int j=0; j<i*2; j++) cout << simbol2;
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```